# How to associate floating IP to specific interface with Heat

Tags: openstack, orchestration, openstack-heat, floating-ip

i am trying to create a stack using openstack HEAT, one of the VMs (`NOVA::Server`) needs to have **2 network interfaces**

so in my hot template i create 2 ports and associate them to the `NOVA::Server` and give a floating IP to one of them `gw_float_port`

```
....
gw_instance:
     type: "OS::Nova::Server"
     properties:
       key_name: { get_param: key_name }
       image: { get_param: image_id }
       flavor: { get_param: instance_type }          
       user_data:"#!/bin/sh \necho \"Starting the OVS setup!\""
       user_data_format: RAW
       networks:
          - port: {get_resource: gw_float_port}
          - port: {get_resource: gw_ovs_port }

gw_float_port:
   type: "OS::Neutron::Port"
   properties:
      network_id: {get_resource: "private_net"}

gw_ovs_port:
   type: "OS::Neutron::Port"
   properties:
      network_id: {get_resource: "private_net"}

floating_ip:
   type: "OS::Neutron::FloatingIP"
   properties:
      floating_network_id: {get_param: "public_network"}
      port_id: {get_resource: "gw_float_port"}
....
```

And when i do an `ifconfig` inside the VM i get the following:

```
 ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:76:98:82
           inet addr:10.4.0.47  Bcast:10.4.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           ....
 ens4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:11:9f:ed
           BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           ....
 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
           ....
```

what i want to know is how to map the NICs from the `ifconfig` with the NICs in the template and control which one gets the floating IP?

within the template (**automatically while creating the stack not with manual manipulation after it is created**)

thanks for you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The floating IP is set to the gw_float_port(NIC) port

You know this because you set the port_id on the FloatingIP resource

```
floating_ip:
   type: "OS::Neutron::FloatingIP"
   properties:
      floating_network_id: {get_param: "public_network"}
      port_id: {get_resource: "gw_float_port"}
```

this is the line that perform the association

```
port_id: {get_resource: "gw_float_port"}
```